# Can't analyse the output (the profile file) of gperftools profiler

Tags: c, profiling, gperftools

I'm using [gperftools](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/) for analysing my C code. An as a result I can't analyze the profile file using `pprof` application.

```
$ gcc -g prog.c -o prog -lprofiler
$ export CPUPROFILE=info.prof
$ ./prog 

 Inside main()

 Inside func1 

 Inside new_func1()

 Inside func2 
PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 1133/0/300
$ ls
info.prof  prog  prog.c
$ ls -lah info.prof 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mm mm 2.6K Jun  6 09:36 info.prof
$ pprof info.prof prog
Reading Profile files in profile.*
Error: Could not open profile.0.0.0: No such file or directory
profile.ftab: No such file or directory
$
```

What do I wrong? What's the `profile.ftab` file?

Comment: isn't it the other way round, `pprof ./prog info.prof`?

Comment: No, the pprof ./prog info.prof command doesn't work too.

Comment: how does the error message look like?

Comment: Similar: Reading Profile files in profile.*
Error: Could not open profile.0.0.0: No such file or directory
profile.ftab: No such file or directory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not using the correct 'pprof' tool. In particular, you're using http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/docs/newguide/bk03ch01s08.html (which is totally unrelated), whereas you need the one here: https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/  I had the same issue and solved the problem by downloading the gperftools' source, building it, and using ./src/pprof

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into this and I think it is worth mentioning how to deal with this in recent versions of Ubuntu (18.04 specifically).

When one tries to run the `pprof` command, the system suggests installing the `tau` package:

```
Command 'pprof' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install tau
```

Do not install that package though, because it is entirely unrelated as David Carney pointed out in his answer. Install the `google-perftools` package instead, but be aware that the executable in it is called `google-pprof` instead of just `pprof`.

Answer (score 1):

You installed the wrong pprof.

If you already have golang installed. You can install pprof using go.
Just do,

```
go get github.com/google/pprof
```

Also install `graphviz` if you want to generate PDFs using

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```